# writing to a file with python

Tags: python

This is a continuation from a question that I had yesterday. I am trying to open a text file that contains a list of numbers. I want to write these numbers to a new file multiple times. The purpose of the loop is to be able to write the source list multiple times. In this example, I want to print a list of 100 numbers 10 times so I end up with a list of 1000 numbers in my output file. This is the code that I am working with:

```
i = 10
while i > 0:
    with open ('C:/TestReq_100 Records.txt', 'r') as ipf:
       for line in ipf:
            num = line.strip()
            filename = 'processed.txt'
            with open('processed.txt', 'w') as opf:
                opf('%s' %num)


##           print num
    i = i - 1
```

If I comment out the code related to writing to file and use the print command in the interpreter, the code does what I want. I just can't seem to get the same output in a text file. Again, I am not a student. Just trying to create files for use in my Company's software for testing purposes...thanks!

Comment: Why are you opening the same file several times? Just open `processed.txt` once (using `a` (=append) instead of `w`), outside the loop, then use `opf.write(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to Levon's answer, there are a few issues with your current program.

- Rather than manually initializing and decrementing an index, try using `xrange` to accomplish the same task in a more concise way.
- You're overwriting processed.txt for each number; you should open it at the same time as the input file.
- What is the purpose of `i`? As it stands, your program is going to do the exact same thing 10 times because `i` is never used inside the loop.
- `'%s' % num` does nothing special when `num` is already a string.

That said, here's a cleaner version of your program, although `i` still does nothing in particular:

```
for i in xrange(10, 0, -1):
    with open('C:/TestReq_100 Records.txt', 'r') as ipf:
        with open('processed.txt', 'w') as opf:
            for line in ipf:
                num = line.strip()
                opf.write(num)
```

You may want to clarify the intended output of this program for a better answer.

EDIT: Here is a more efficient solution for copying a file into a new file multiple times:

```
# Read the input data once.
with open('C:/TestReq_100 Records.txt', 'r') as ipf:
    ipdata = ipf.read()
# Add a newline to the end of the file if there isn't already one present.
# Without this, the last and first lines of the input might become single lines.
if ipdata[-1] != '\n':
    ipdata += '\n'
# Write to the output file multiple times.
with open('processed.txt', 'w') as opf:
    for i in xrange(10):
        opf.write(ipdata)
```

Comment: should I append rather then write?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to accomplish. In its current state, the code I posted will open `TestReq_100 Records.txt` and write its contents line-by-line to `processed.txt`, then repeat that 10 times, overwriting it each time. If you want `processed.txt` to contain 10 back-to-back copies of the input file, you can make it append, but I can't give you much help beyond that without knowing what you're expecting the program to do.

Comment: that is exactly what I want the program to do...I want to be able to change the number of times the list is written to the new file. I may need to loop through 10,000 times to yield a new list with 1,000,000 lines.

Comment: In that case, yes, you would change `'w'` to `'a'` to append. But there are much more efficient ways to accomplish that. I'll revise my code in a moment.

Comment: @Fraxtil- That did the trick! Thanks very much for the assist. I thought I was close but this new code is written much better than my attempt. I will try and be more specific in future postings. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2):

You don't exactly state what the problem in the output is, but try this:

```
 opf.write('%s\n' %num)
```

instead of

```
 opf('%s' %num)
```

*Notes*:

1. You are calling the `write` method on the the output file object
2. You are appending a newline (`\n`) to your output, `print` does this by default, to this should make your print and this equivalent.

You are opening and the *same* file over and over and writing to it, is that your intention? You will only retain whatever your wrote last to that file.  A bit *more details in your post* (about the specific problem with the output, and your given input and desired output would make it easier to help you accomplish your goal)

**UPDATE** based on more information in the comment below.

Structure your program along these lines (though the exact order is a bit *iffy* given the lack of clear specifications, you can use this as a guide):

```
with open ('C:/TestReq_100 Records.txt') as ipf:
    with open('processed.txt', 'w') as opf:
        i = 10
        while i > 0:
            for line in ipf:
                num = line.strip()
                filename = 'processed.txt'
                write.opf('%s\n' %num)
##           print num
            i = i - 1
```

The output file is opened *once* before the loops.

By the way, if you are using a fairly recent version of Python, you can collapse both `with` statements into one:

```
with open('C:/TestReq_100 Records.txt') as ipf,open('processed.txt','w') as opf:
```

Note that you could have used two for-loops, ie replace the current while loop with a for loop, but that's more a matter of style and semantics, it won't affect the functionality of the code.

Comment: I tried that and I didn't receive an error,  but it appears that the numbers are overwriting each other, leaving me with one line in the new file which is the last number in the series...

Comment: @hnathan You'll need to open the outputfile before the loop, I'll update my answer.

Comment: I want to read the list of numbers from the input file and then copy the list multiple times to a new file...

Comment: @hnathan I think the code now does what you want. I would be **much** easier to know how to help you if you provided some sample input/outputs, otherwise there's a bit of guessing involved :)

Comment: Trying this code I ended up with my list of 100 numbers written to the new file. I am trying to get the list written 10 times to end up with a list of 1000 numbers in the output file...I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what your problem was, but it looks like you have at least two issues.

First, you're opening the same file in `'w'` mode multiple times.  `'w'` mode will not append to an existing file, it will overwrite an existing file.  So you'll only get the last iteration of the loop. You can resolve this by opening the file before the loop begins and closing it after it ends.  You can still do this with the `with` syntax if you want.

Second, I think you need to use `opf.write()` instead of just `opf()` unless that's a syntax I'm not aware of.

Try this:

```
with open ('C:/TestReq_100 Records.txt', 'r') as ipf:
    with open('processed.txt', 'w') as opf:
        i = 10
        while i > 0:
            for line in ipf:
                num = line.strip()
                filename = 'processed.txt'
                opf.write('%s' %num)
            i = i - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, this should do it... (in 2.7.x)

```
from itertools import islice

MAX = 10

with open('infile') as fin, open('outfile', 'w') as fout:
    for line in islice(fin, MAX):
        print >> fout, line.strip()
```